# Is Picture Library Slideshow Web Part available in O365 Education A2 plan?

Tags: office-365, licensing, slidelibrary

Well, the title says pretty much all: I do not have such a plan available at the moment, but I need to understand if that plan includes the *Picture Library Slideshow Web Part* out-of-the-box.

I'm planning to add that webpart on pages in the public facing website of an Office 365 account for a school (again, this is not yet available).

I've searched around, but I was only able to find *partial* answers, like on this [O365 help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/add-a-slide-show-to-a-web-page-HA104092377.aspx) where it says "Applies to", or this [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx) on plans (but there's no mention on webparts).

Is there a way to find out this for sure (by means of some reference page)?

Comment: I am looking for the same answer. Have you found out yet?

Comment: Please have a look at the answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what we found by way of experimenting:

We started a trial SPO with A2 Education license. That web part was not included by default in such a plan. But then we were able to grab a copy of the web part file (it was freely available from some Microsoft page, I don't have the URL right now) and upload it in the Intranet Web Part gallery.

At that point, the web part was available in the site for use.